# How do I share my application's Room database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room, android-sharing

I'd like to share my app's internal database as a SQLite file.
Here's my naïve attempt. It doesn't raise any Exception but never succeeds either, depending on the application I choose to share, I get "Unsupported attachment" (Telegram), "Upload was unsuccessful" (Drive), "Couldn't attach file" (Gmail), …

```kotlin
private fun shareData() {
    val dbPath = application.getDatabasePath(LOCAL_DB_NAME).path
    try {
        val shareIntent = Intent()
        shareIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(dbPath))
        shareIntent.type = "application/x-sqlite3"
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Data"))
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an invalid `Uri` in general. Even if you switched to `Uri.forFile()`, that would not help, as passing a `file://` `Uri` between apps has been banned for several years.

Use `FileProvider` to share files between apps. FWIW, I cover `FileProvider` in [this section](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-files-005.html) of [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/). See also [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing), [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing), and [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/share-file).

Comment: `FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.example.myapp.provider", File(application.getDatabasePath(LOCAL_DB_NAME).toURI()))` fails with `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/com.example.myapp/databases/my_database` although the file is there, is it because of an incorrect setup in the paths in the xml ? (I set it as `<files-path name="databases" path="/" />`)

Comment: @YeO: Hmmm... officially, `getDatabasePath()` is not a location that can be served by `FileProvider`. I did not take that into account with my answer, for which I apologize. You could try switching to `<root-path name="root" path="."/>`, which is undocumented but still works with the current `FileProvider` implementation.

Comment: Thanks! Android Studio complains that "<root-path> is not allowed here" but doesn't make a big deal out of it, however, I'm now getting `android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapp/databases/my_database exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()`

Comment: @Yeo: Somewhere, you are still using a `File` with your `Intent` directly. A `FileProvider` `Uri` will not look like that.

Comment: yup, stupid me, it works now! Many thanks, sir